# LocationClient.getLastLocation() returns Null although connected

Tags: android, gps, location-client

iam trying to receive my current location through the LocationClient but for some reason it returns null. I dont NOT want to use GPS therefore i have dummied out the fine location access permission in my Manifest.

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> -->
```

MainActivity:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
....
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this); 
....
}

@Override
   protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      // Connect the client.
      mLocationClient.connect();
}

@Override
   protected void onStop() {
      // Disconnect the client.
      mLocationClient.disconnect();
      super.onStop();
   }

@Override
   public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
      location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
       // do something with the current location
   }
```

For some reason it always returns null for location unless i open the settings on my phone and enable GPS. Once GPS is enabled i am able to get my location. It does get the location through the network though. i dont want to use GPS and i dont want it to be enabled. But if GPS is not enabled it doesnt get a location at all.
any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: That is the functionality of coarse, you have to activate the GPS service from your phone. If you don't want to use the GPS service you need to activate your fine permission.

Comment: wow thanks now it really seems to be working... i always thought fine location would be GPS.. Thats why i removed this permission

Comment: I did the same thing when I first started, seems counter-intuitive until you stat realizing what everything is actually doing.

Comment: @zgc7009 that's a very inaccurate statement at best. Coarse returns network position. Fine returns GPS. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION . The reason why LocationService returns null may be that there is no coarse location available. The service does not return a fine location to an app that does not have that permisson.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use GPS than it will get location from Network, enable it in your device as mentioned in below screenshot

[image]

Comment: yes thats the problem.. when i disable GPS i dont get a location at all

Comment: @user3425561: I am talking about enabling checkbox of `Use wireless networks` so that it can provide you locations using network provider.